# Real Analysis: basic clarification

Tags: real-analysis

$A=(0,3)$. Are $(0,3)$ all limit points or just point at $0$ and $3$?

Is $[0,1)$ closed? I think it is not closed because it does not contain its limit point $1$.

Comment: 1) Limit points of $(0,3)$ are all the points in $[0,3]$. 2) $[0,1)$ is not closed, as you say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the definition of a limit point in a set $S$. $x \in S$ is a limit point, if every ball around $x$ contains at least one point in $S$ other than $x$.

Now let us look at a point in the interval $(0,3)$, say $1$. Every ball around $1$ contains at least one point in the set $S$ other than $1$. Hence, $1$ is a limit point. This is in fact true for all $x \in [0,3]$. Hence, the set of limit points of $(0,3)$ is $[0,3]$.

And your answer for the second question is correct.

Answer (score 0):

First you should check the definition of the limit point before posting the question.Here the limit point set of A is $[0,3]$.
about $[0,1)$ your thinking is correct.